# DownloadManager a file from assets folder? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I'm making a soundboard application and I want users to be able to download files from assets so they can set it as a notification sound/ringtone. I'm getting an error saying I can only download files from HTTP/HTTPS. Is there a way around this?

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("content://com.thingy.app/" + filename));
request.setDescription("Soundbite from ");
request.setTitle(filename);
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to copy a SQLite database out of the Assets folder to internal storage:

```
        //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_IN);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `AssetManager` and [its `open()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open(java.lang.String)) to get an `InputStream` on the asset content. Then, copy the bytes to a `FileOutputStream` on the file that you want to create.